# SciPy setup can't find Fortran on Mac

Tags: python, fortran, scipy

I have numpy, Xcode 4.5.1, Python 2.7.3, and gfortran 4.2.4-5666.3 installed. The latter I installed from Homebrew, which it put in /usr/local/Cellar. Running setup.py in the scipy folder results in the familiar "Could not locate executable " errors. I grep'd for where these compilers are referenced to try to point Python to the right place but came up with nothing. Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Dunno, but if you can, I would just install the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) available here: http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

Comment: That's too bad. Got EPD installed and it seems to work. Thanks!